# How to copy set of files with defined delay

Tags: linux, file, copy

I need to copy some set of files in Linux from one directory to another (~100 files). And I need to copy them with defined delay: 1 second for example.

If I copy them with "cp" command it happend really fast. File sizes just few kb.

I didn't found keys for "cp" command to copy files with delay.

File names are different and contain time+identifier, so it's not easy to use simple counter like:

```
for (i = 0, i<100, i++){
  filename = "name" + i
}
```

How to realize this task with simple script?

I think it should be something like:

```
list a = ls "current dir"
while list[i] != null
   cp list[i] "destFolder"
   i++
```

Thanks for help

```
 Right answer: find ./folder1/* -exec cp {} folder2/ \; -exec sleep 3 \;
```

Comment: Use `cron` or `at` for this purpose. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html

Comment: Why do you need the delay?  To give some rest to the processor?

Comment: I need to test application which will receive something about 100 files per day and approximatly 1 file per minute max speed and should proceed them correctly. So I don't need to receive all files immediatly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use find with -exec for example

```
find . -exec cp {} ../newdir \; -exec sleep 1 \;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason, but it works when inverted: 
`find . -exec sleep 1 \; -exec cp {} ../newdir \;`